# Не работает lru_cache(None)

Tags: python

Хоть я и выставил неограниченное количество рекурсии, но программа все равно заканчивается на ошибке **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded**

```
from functools import *
@lru_cache(None)


def foo(n):
    if n >= 10000:
        return n
    if (n < 10000) and (n % 2 == 0):
        return 1 + foo(n / 2)
    if (n < 10000) and (n % 2 == 1):
        return (n ** 2) + foo(n + 2)
    
for i in 9, 192:
    foo(i)
```

Comment: Кеш не может вернуть того, чего в нем нет. У вас просто уникальных ключей, которых нет еще в кеше, набирается достаточно для превышения лимита. Для этого куска кода кеш всего лишь в 2 раза отодвигает лимит, но этого все равно мало. Так что тут еще нужно увеличивать лимит `sys.setrecursionlimit(...)`, который по умолчанию `1000`

Comment: Если увеличивать лимит `sys.setrecursionlimit(...)`, то при вызове например `foo(2001)` не выведется вообще ничего

Comment: Вот вы пишете "неограниченное количество рекурсии", но это не так. `@lru_cache(None)` выключает лишь вытеснение старых значений (можно вообще взять `@cache` из того же `functools`). То есть сам `lru_cache` работает, а то что "слишком много рекурсии в таком алгоритме и как его переписать" - совсем другой вопрос. Увы, но автор питона не сторонник оптимизации хвостовой рекурсии, потому подобный огород придется городить самому.

Comment: Я понял что имеется ввиду под ключами, и уже понял в чем проблема и как ее решить без `sys.setrecursionlimit(...)`, большое спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в `foo` подаётся нечётное число, то она начинает рекурсивно ходить по одной и той же ветке кода:

```py
    if (n < 10000) and (n % 2 == 1):
        return (n ** 2) + foo(n + 2)
```

Потому что `n + 2` - это тоже нечётное число в случае, если `n` было нечётное. Перебираются все нечётные числа подряд, начиная с начального:

```
9
11
13
15
...
9997
9999
10001
```

Таким образом, в этой ветке будет совершено `(10000 - n - 1) / 2` рекурсивных итераций. Для `n = 9` с которого вы начинаете, это будет `4995`, не каждый интерпретатор питона может выдержать такую степень рекурсии, даже если вы и повысите её лимит.

Причём, повышать уровень рекурсии нужно выше этого числа, там есть и другие накладные расходы.

P.S. С чётной веткой у вас тоже смешно. Если напечатать `n` с которым происходит обращение к функции, то получится:

```
192
96.0
48.0
24.0
12.0
6.0
3.0
5.0
7.0
9.0
11.0
13.0
15.0
...
```

То есть сначала чётное число, которого, конечно же, нет в кэше, потом чётные числа с плавающей точкой, которых опять же нет в кэше, а дальше числа нечётные, но не целые, как было при первом прогоне с `n = 9`, а с плавающей точкой. Для кэша целые числа и числа с плавающей точкой - это **разные числа**!

В итоге кэш у вас вообще ни разу не сработал, это можно проверить по статистике использования кэша:

```
print(foo.cache_info())
# CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=10003, maxsize=None, currsize=10003)
```

Значение `hits=0` говорит нам о том, что значение из кэша ни разу не было использовано.

И да, я надеюсь вы понимаете, что `for i in 9, 192:` - это цикл всего по двум числам: `9` и `192`? Это кортеж. Вот если бы вы сделали такой цикл `for i in range(9, 192):`, то кэш мог бы быть использован и довольно эффективно. А сейчас у вас что есть кэш, что нет - абсолютно никакой разницы, он совсем не используется.